# Настройка подсветки блоков кода в QT Creator

Tags: qtcreator

Помогите настроить(починить) QT Creator(6.0.2).  Я хочу видеть границы блоков кода, например :

```
if(condition){
|    ------
|    ------
|    ------
|    ------
|    a lot of code
|    ------
}
```

Как тут(VScode):

[image]

Однако в QTCreator-e отображение такое:

[image]

ассоциация : [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73905941/qt-creator-lines-that-draw-boundaries-of-block/73906892#73906892)

Comment: Что-то я не помню такой функции в QT Creator. Подсветка блоков есть, но она работает иначе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По ответу поддержки данная функция доступна в Qt Creator 9.0.0-beta1